# C error with structs and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
typedef struct stnode {
    unsigned number;
    char * name;
    unsigned section;
    struct stnode * next;
} StudentNode; 

void buildStudentSections(StudentNode * sections[], StudentNode students[], size_t num_students) {

        if(!num_students) return ;
        StudentNode * aux=NULL;

        for(int i=0;i<num_students;i++){

            aux=sections[students[i].section];
            (**(sections+students[i].section)).next=*(students+i);


            }   

    }
```

When I try do execute this code I have this error:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct stnode *’ from type ‘StudentNode’
```

What is the problem with the code, I already tried lots of things, but non have worked. I just want to refer the next to the "student" that i'm analyzing

Answer (score 2):

Read the *compiler error* (you are not executing this code yet - it hasn't compiled...)

> ‘struct stnode *’ from type ‘StudentNode’

Basically you are trying to assign a structure to a pointer, this doesn't work. Look at the following line:

```
(**(sections+students[i].section)).next=*(students+i);
```

The problem lies in the *de-reference* of `(students + 1)`.

Comment: Now im receiving the error line 7:  1961 Segmentation fault Why?

Comment: We cannot answer this, you need to *debug* - get the program to generate a *core* file and then fire up your *debugger* and look at the core.

Comment: Without seeing how this is called, there is no way to know exactly how the fault is occurring.

Comment: int main() {
 

 StudentNode student = { 11111, "Afonso Henriques", 1, NULL };
 StudentNode * sections[3] = { NULL, NULL, NULL };
 
  buildStudentSections(sections, &student, 1);

 return 0;
}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `*(students+i)` is de-referencing the element `students+i`. It should be:

```
(**(sections+students[i].section)).next=students+i;
```

Comment: Now im receiving the error line 7:  1961 Segmentation fault Why?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
void buildStudentSections(StudentNode * sections[], StudentNode students[], size_t num_students) {

        if(!num_students) return ;
        StudentNode * aux=NULL;

        for(int i=0;i<num_students;i++){

            aux=sections[students[i].section];       // = *(x) you are dereferencing students+1
            (**(sections+students[i].section)).next=*(students+i);


            }   

    }
```

To this:

```
void buildStudentSections(StudentNode * sections[], StudentNode students[], size_t num_students) 
{

        if(!num_students) return ;
        StudentNode * aux=NULL;

        for(int i=0;i<num_students;i++)
        {

            aux=sections[students[i].section];      //removed '*`
            (**(sections+students[i].section)).next = (students+1); 


        }   

}
```